# Running multiple Eclipse confiugrations in succession

Tags: eclipse, maven, configuration, build, sequence

I have one Eclipse configuration defined that's a Maven build. I've got another one defined that's an unrelated Maven build too.

Now I want to create a sequence that runs the first one and then the second one as soon as the first one is finished. Is that possible in Eclipse?

P. S.: I need this for testing purposes.

Comment: Sounds more like a job for an continious integration solution like Jenkins/Hudson etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I've found no way to do this.